# How to Show Different Products Depending on Google Translate Widget Language Chosen

Tags: javascript, php, google-translate

I am developing a website with shopping cart that will have different products per country. Customer wants to use Google Translate to change language.

We thought one website with different product categories for each country would be best. So someone in France chooses FR in Google Translate, and we have some code to show the FR product category.

But I cant find how to determine in my website code (PHP) what language is chosen by the Google Translate Widget. The URL stays the same, so I cannot query the URL.

How would one be able to determine at the server level (PHP) what language has been chosen by the Google Translate Widget?

I wonder if this is even possible as its probably using Javascript to change it, so would there be other ways to tap into the Google Translate Widget so I could use Javascript to show the correct product category?

This is the Google Widget Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
    {
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        includedLanguages: 'en,cy',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
    },
    'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Google Translate widgets are only a very rough method to translate a site and give the visitor a general idea of what is on that page. Automatic machine translation does not have the quality to replace an actual localisation, and especially if you need it integrated with your site on a business logic level it's not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Yes we know its machine and lower quality

Comment: I found out I can add #googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE) to the URL to auto-translate so potentially tap into that in my code, BUT... what an awful string to append to the URL. I wish we could auto Google translate based on sub-folder /fr for example.

Comment: Keep in mind that the consumed language not always matches the users country, and most people disable autotranslation for languages they can read (e.g. english). So you can serve different products per language, but should not rely on language to serve "different products per country".

Comment: understood, but thats OK we will not offer a French Store in the German language for example. Its supposed to be a country's own website not a translation of another country's website.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, but not ideal due to horrible hashes in the URL...

Google can auto translate the page content if you add #googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE) to the end of the URL, e.g. www.mydomain.com#googtrans(en|fr)

So setup a multi-country site like standard, e.g. /fr, /de etc. (sub-domains could be used or anything in the URL to specify what country, e.g. ?country=fr).

Using links to each country section of the site, link to the country section with the hash on the end, e.g. www.mydomain.com/fr#googtrans(en|fr) or fr.mydomain.com#googtrans(en|fr) or www.mydomain.com?country=fr#googtrans(en|fr)

The country section in the URL, e.g. /fr allows you to show the correct store for that country (and anything else you want to display for that country, perhaps call different images as Google cant translate those), and then the hash allows Google to translate it to the correct language.

Its a horrible hash to use! Be good if we could not use the hash and just translate based on just /fr (probably can do this using the non-free API but this is just for the free widget).

Note: Its probably necessary to exclude the country sections e.g. /fr from being indexed in Google, because I would hazard a guess Google may see the original language content on these sub-sections before its JS translation kicks in, so we would not want that duplicate content. I do not believe Google indexes the widget translated pages, so just disallow these sections in the robots.txt file.

Comment: An alternative that would allow the hash not to be used, is to pass a variable to pageLanguage: 'en' based on the country we are on on the site, e.g. pageLanguage: country, and add autoDisplay: true to the JS. In theory this should work, BUT I have not managed to get this to work, autoDisplay does not seem to be working, and I cant see how to pass this variable.